# Feathers UI custom itemRenderer Texture

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I was wondering if someone knows (and would like to share) how to use textures in a custom itemRenderer?

Bascially I want to be able to show something like:

```
X    X    Item name 1     Item detail 1     X
X    X    Item name 2     Item detail 2     X
X    X    Item name 3     Item detail 3     X
X    X    Item name 4     Item detail 4     X
```

where X is an image/texture.

I have tried in my main class file

```
itemListArray.push({image1: Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("texture-name-1"), image2: Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("texture-name-1"), label1: "Item name 1", label2: "Item detail 1", image3: Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("texture-name-3")});
```

and also tried adding the texture directly into the custom item renderer class but I cannot get it to display. I am sure this is probably the wrong way to going about using images/icons in item renderers.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Added the asset in the actual item renderer and created a boolean to show/hide on the item renderer.